# Get users pending envelopes which was sent by any sender

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I have a below use case in my application:

Get users pending envelopes. I have to find all pending envelopes for any user using email Id. Any sender can send the envelopes to any user and I have to find the list of the envelopes the user has pending actions.

Which endpoint should I use to get this information ?

I have tried to get envelopes using account id. But for only single user I can able to find the list of envelopes.

I want to get any user's envelopes list using email id and these envelopes can be sent by any sender.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, DocuSign does not have a method to query envelopes by recipient email address, however, you can obtain this information by combining:

Our Envelope list
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/list-envelope-status-changes/

and

The recipients for an envelope
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-recipients/

We hope this helps

Regards
Adrian
DocuSign Developer Support